# How should I seal this gap between spigot and stucco wall?

Tags: plumbing, stucco, caulk, sealant

[image: Spigot penetration through wall]

Options I've seen include silicone caulk, stucco patch mix, or duct seal. What will work best? It will rain in about 17 hours, so a quick drying method will be useful, or I can maybe just cover it with something for now.

Comment: Duct seal is removable. With silicone caulk, make sure you use a metal-safe non-acid-curing version.